# TFS 2010 Build Template to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015

Can anyone help with what all challenges can I face while updating TFS 2010 build template to TFS 2015?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the challenges?

Comment: @Abhishek Jain, 1). if the TFS2010 server is already upgraded to TFS2015 successfully, you can just use 2015 version build template, why you would like to migrate? 2). Did you customize TFS2010 build template? 3). Does the TFS2010 build template contain some custom build activities?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT: Yes we have customized build template in 2010 and now we want to upgrade TFS to 2015. I am just looking for the challenges I can face while updating custom build template from 2010 to 2015.

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded to TFS 2015 and we didn't experience any issues with our build templates.

We have highly customized templates and a bunch of custom activities. They all work with no issues whatsoever.

I think you will be fine.

On the other hand, if you want to start using Build vNext, you won't be able to just migrate your XAML definitions as far as I know.